# UWP DataGrid get selected cell

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, datagrid

I have issues getting selected cell in data grid (using UWP).
I am using DataGrid from this library: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.controls.datagrid?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-7.0

Any ideas how to get it? It was pretty straight forward in WPF DataGrid, but pretty much all cell related functionality is not present here... :(

All help is appreciated, thanks.

FYI: There is event CurrentCellChanged, which works as expected, but returns empty EventArgs and there is no public property to access the current cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a property of the [DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.controls.datagrid?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-7.0) called **CurrentColumn**. You could get the column that contains the current cell via this property. Like this:

```
 DataGridColumn gridColumn = dataGrid1.CurrentColumn;
```

Then you could call the [DataGridColumn.GetCellContent()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.controls.datagridcolumn.getcellcontent?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-7.0#microsoft-toolkit-uwp-ui-controls-datagridcolumn-getcellcontent(microsoft-toolkit-uwp-ui-controls-datagridrow)) to get the content of current cell. For example:

```
 TextBlock contentElement = gridColumn.GetCellContent(dataGrid1.SelectedItem as Customer) as TextBlock;

        var cellvalue = contentElement.Text;
```

And of course, if you have a tag or something in the column that could help you detect which property is the one you are looking for, you could directly get the cell value from the `dataGrid1.SelectedItem`. For example:

```
Customer selectedCustomer = dataGrid1.SelectedItem as Customer;

var cellvalue = selectedCustomer.Address;
```